# How to select ESD TVS diode?

Tags: diodes, protection, circuit-protection, esd, tvs

This is the following specification of my circuit
Vin 8V to 32V
The breakdown voltage should be 33V of TVS
I don't know what clamping voltage means please simplify it for me

What should be Vc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum clamping voltage is the voltage across the TVS when it is carrying the specified current. Consider [this](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=2b2f4a8c-2e81-4894-8d41-3d748bb79e68&filename=littelfuse-tvs-diode-5-0smdj-datasheet) Littelfuse TVS datasheet as an example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The breakdown voltage of the bottom model number is somewhere between 36.7 and 40.6V when it is conducting a small amount of current (1mA). The Reverse standoff voltage is specified as 33V so it is suitable for a 32V maximum input.

The clamping voltage is specified as 53.3V (maximum) at 93.9A (test current) so if you need your circuit to withstand that particular current **you must design your circuit to withstand a momentary voltage of at least 53.3V**.

For currents between 1mA and 93.9A the voltage can be more than 40.6V but less than 53.3V. So a 40V device would be inadequately protected and a 60V rating would be prudent. Things like resistors that can withstand brief overloads may be okay or may need to be beefed up. Capacitors and ICs, less so. You may be able to find typical voltage vs. current curves for the particular TVS device and you would need to adjust those to estimate the worst-case voltage if it's not at the specific guaranteed test values of current.

You don't have a free choice of voltages, once you know your the maximum operating voltage (which determines your standoff voltage requirement), the clamping voltage will be considerably higher for a given series of TVS devices.

Comment: +1 If you expect less than the maximum clamping current, you can approximate the reduced clamping voltage based on the dynamic resistance figure which is also given in TVS datasheets.

Comment: @tobalt There is a curve of typical voltage vs. current  but only for the '5V' model that I can see. Maybe more information is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

clamping voltage refers to the maximum voltage that the diode will allow to pass through it when it's conducting. When a voltage spike occurs in the circuit, the TVS diode conducts to limit the voltage across the circuit to a safe level.

your given circuit specification shows:

```
Input voltage (Vin): 8V to 32V
The breakdown voltage of TVS: 33V
```

In this case, when the input voltage exceeds 33V (due to a transient voltage spike), the TVS diode will start conducting to limit the voltage across the circuit. The voltage at which it starts conducting is known as the clamping voltage (VC Or VCL).
for example in the datasheet of the PESD2CANFD2V-T TVS Diode you you will see a photo like the one below

Picture reference: https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/916/PESD2CANFD27V_T-2585511.pdf
[image: TVS]

According to the figure shown, the diode allows a small current to pass until it approaches its conduction voltage (VBr). However, as soon as the threshold voltage is reached, a large current suddenly passes through the diode. This characteristic arises from the intrinsic behavior of the PN junction specification, which is beyond the scope of this discussion. ( you can read more about it in the link: https://study.com/academy/lesson/p-n-junction-diode-definition-properties.html)

Another important issue to consider when choosing TVS diodes is their performance speed in connection with high-speed signals.

Comment: Alirezaagha30 - Hi, Please ensure that you properly follow the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing). You copied material from elsewhere and, although you added a link, there was no indication that the text was *copied* because you didn't use blockquotes to quote it. I added the required blockquotes there. || The second paragraph in this answer also looks like it is closely reworded from the same external webpage, but is not referenced. Note that even closely reworded text must be acknowledged with a reference (see the 2nd paragraph of that site rule).

Comment: (continued) In general, I would advise against *rewording* text from elsewhere in an answer here - it can look like the source is being deliberately hidden. Instead either copy directly (then use blockquotes for that text here, and add a correct reference), or use completely your own words. || It's not clear for the last paragraph, how much is a copy, or closely-reworded, since again you have not used blockquotes, but have given a link. Please check whether you are complying with the site rule & fix it, if needed. || P.S. That DevX site looks like its text is AI-generated :(

Comment: This text provides several inconsistent explanations for what clamping voltage means, and therefore is not a good answer.

Comment: My dear friend @tobalt, I tried to explain this issue from different points of view to make it easier to understand